# How to add and retrieve the values in Arraylist of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I know how to **create** an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`, but how to **add** new `ArrayList` and **add** value to that particular `ArrayList` and how to **retrieve** the data from that list.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Comment: Have you tried `arrayList.get(index).add(Integer);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how to add new ArrayLists and ADD value to that particular ArrayList
>   and how to RETRIEVE the data form that list.

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayList=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> newAL= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    arrayList.add(newAL);
    newAL.add(1);
    newAL.add(2);
    newAL.clear();      
    System.out.println(arrayList.get(0));
    //Changes persist in your arraylist
```

So after adding ArrayList you can manipulate `newAL` as `ArrayList` **stores reference** you don't need to fetch and set element from main `arrayList`.

---

To retrive data you can `Iterate`(Use [ForEach Loop](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html)) over `arrayList` or you can do following

```
    Integer List0Item1=arrayList.get(0).get(1);//Get first element of list at 0
    arrayList.get(0).set(0, 10);//set 0th element of list at 0 as 10
    ArrayList<Integer> list10=arrayList.get(10);//get arraylist at position 10
```

Comment: thanks..but can you please let me know the use of newAL.clear() ?

Comment: @user3209819 Sure Why not,[`newAL.clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear%28%29) removes all elements from `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list1=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list2=new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(1); // add to list
    list1.add(2);
    list2.add(3);
    list2.add(4);
    arrayList.add(list1); // add to list of list
    arrayList.add(list2);
    for(ArrayList<Integer> i:arrayList){ // iterate -list by list
        for(Integer integer:i){ //iterate element by element in a list

        }
    }
```

You can get element directly

```
  arrayList.get(0).get(0); // 0th list 0th value
```

adding value to 0th list

```
 arrayList.get(0).add(1);  // 1 will add to 0th index list-list1
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a list of list where every object of the parent list is in turn a sublist.The code is something like below:

```
List<List<String>> mainList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();  

      List<String> sublist1 = new ArrayList<String>();  
      sublist1.add("State");
      sublist1.add("Country");
      sublist1.add("City");

      mainList .add(sublist1); 

      List<String> sublist2 = new ArrayList<String>();  
      sublist2.add("Sleep");
      sublist2.add("Suspend");
      sublist2.add("Wait");

      mainList .add(sublist2); 

      for(List<String> obj:mainList){ // iterate 
            for(String value:obj){

                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }

}
}
    Hope this will help to clear your doubt.
```